# How can I find failure reason for creating Sql Job in Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a PowerShell script to create a Sql Job. I have used this script before but for some reason this time it is not working. I don't know how to find the failure reason. I only get this error message:

> Exception calling "Create" with "0" argument(s): "Create failed for
>   Job 'UBASS_LMS - FullSyncCorrespondence'. " At line:75 char:13
>   +             $job.Create()
>   +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedOperationException

Can I enable anything to see this during the powershell execution? or can this be viewed somewhere in msdb?

Comment: try to get more detailed error information using `$error[0] | fl * -force`. Also - may you share your script with us?

Comment: Thanks I didn't know you can do that to see the fill error. That would have saved me hours. I found the issue in the full error.THANKS. Put it as an answer and I iwill mark it